# How to compare two outputs of data in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I created 5 rooms with same Game id and print result (list if Rooms' id). i get Game with Id and print result (list of Rooms' id. I need to check if this two outputs (rooms id are matches).

```
for i in range(5):
           post_req = requests.post(custom_url)  # create 5 custom rooms with same Game id

           json_data = post_req.text
           python_data = json.loads(json_data)
           for i in range(len(python_data["data"])):
               first_list = python_data["data"][i]["id"]
               print (first_list)
# Get Rooms with Game id. It should give a list of all rooms id created with same game id
 custom_get_objects = requests.get(custom_url) 

 json_data = custom_get_objects.text
 python_get_data = json.loads(json_data)
 for i in range(len(python_get_data["data"])):
     second_list = python_get_data["data"][i]["id"]
     print (second_list)
```

How to program next following logic?

if first_list.data == second_list.data: 
      return True

my list.data output:

```
2b88a706-0ae0-4cac-84b3-8f69657ac8cd
402210ca-8397-4329-9c96-770f1d93ab43
78c9faae-74ad-44f8-9bab-b54bb8815afb
9a374566-d992-40a8-9e23-9cfe83ced532
f39794ed-d2f1-4443-a3f3-ef12534387d6
```

i tried to sort and iterated one list in another, but output is not what i expected. If you know or have any idea, please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read [ask].  Without an example of the data you are operating on, it may be difficult for us to help.

Comment: You should switch to Python 3.6+ while you are still learning - it is an improvement on 2.7.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will read. sorry if i broke the rules.

Comment: No problem - the easier you make it for us to reproduce your problem the more likely we are to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order in your lists does not matter you can use `sorted(listA) == sorted(listB)` to compare them. If the order matters then simply use `listA == listB`.

**Example:**

```
aList = [2, 4, 5]
bList = [2, 5, 4]

print(aList == bList)
print(sorted(aList) == sorted(bList))
```

Output:

```
False
True
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have applied your solution and did not work. I updated my original post with data output. Do you thin thank i need to convert into string each line?

Comment: It worked. I just need to do: sorted(python_data) == sorted(python_get_data). Thanks for help.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If the answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted :)